# Ruby copying between active model objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Simply trying to work out how to copy attributes from one Active Model to another without having to do it one by one.

I have two models one is RFM (ruby to filemaker) one is mongoid both mixin active model.

```
gem "ginjo-rfm"
```

the model

```
require 'rfm'

class StudentAdmin < Rfm::Base
  config :layout => 'STUDENT_ADMIN_LAYOUT'
  attr_accessor :name_first,:name_last
end
```

Mongoid model

```
class Student
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
end
```

Is there a quicky copy I can do? I found a sample between active record objects e.g.

```
 student_admin = ... #load StudentAdmin
 Student.new(student_admin.attributes.slice(Student.attribute_names))
```

but RFM doesn't provide a attributes method.

### EDIT

Sorry what I am trying to achive is a better way than this

```
student_admins = #get student admins from external service
students = []
student_admins.each() do |sa|
students.push(Student.create!(first_name: sa.name_first, last_name: sa.name_last)) 
end
```

This example only shows 2 attributes, but in practice there is over 50 and was wondering if there is a way to do it without having to specify every attribute e.g. if the attribute names are the same on two objects copy them automatically.

Comment: Are you just trying to migrate each `StudentAdmin` record to a corresponding `Student` record?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
students = student_admins.map do |sa|
  attrs = sa.methods.inject({}) do |hash, m|
    next unless Student.column_names.include? m.to_s
    hash[m] = sa.send m
  end
  Student.create(attrs)
end
```

`Student` would have to be a class that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

Comment: sorry thats not exactly what I meant, I have edited my question

Comment: I understand now. Changed my answer, let me know how it works.